# Push initiator access in blackberry push notification

Tags: blackberry-eclipse-plugin

Recently i am working with push notification in blackberry.I have even installed the BPSS(BLackberry push service sdk)They have provided me Apache tomcat Server sdk for blackberry.I have configured it locally and run  the push sample initiator.But else i have obtained the following:

```
 Sample Push Initiator
Push #  0 / 100  
Application Id  sampleappid  
Application Level
Reliability false    
Delay (s)   300  
State   General Push Active  
The following options each push to all active subscribers.
"Start General Push" sends an identical message to all active subscribers.
"Start Personalized Push" sends a unique message to each active subscriber.


Push #  Push Id Time/Date Sent  Push Outcome
1       Thu May 03 17:19:44 IST 2012    ERROR: There are no active subscribers.
1       Thu May 03 17:24:45 IST 2012    ERROR: There are no active subscribers.
1       Thu May 03 17:29:46 IST 2012    ERROR: There are no active subscribers.
1       Thu May 03 17:34:46 IST 2012    ERROR: There are no active subscribers.
1       Thu May 03 17:39:46 IST 2012    ERROR: There are no active subscribers.


v1.1 Copyright © 2011 Research In Motion Limited, unless otherwise noted.
```

Can anybody help me out in resolving the subscribe and unsubcribe issue related to the Blackberry push.

Answer (score 0):

Have to register your client push application ?
if not then register it first and they you will able to receive the push notification.
Use net.rim.blackberry.api.push package.